# How to destroy previously created view instance while creating the new instance for the same view in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I am using Backbone.js in my project.
I have created a new instance of a view in a render function of another view

```
render: function (data) {
    var newView = new View();
}
```

need to call same render function again and again without refreshing the page. if i do so, it creates multiple instances.
How do i destroy/hide the previously created instance before creating the new one?

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to your view and then destroy it when you create a new instance with [`view.remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) / [`view.undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) / custom code  to completely detach it:

```
render: function() {
    if (this.subview)
        this.subview.remove();

    this.subview = new View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a straightforward approach. I have used it many times.

Assuming you have a global variable declared (say '`globalHandle`)

```
render: function (data) {
    if(globalHandle.newView)
      return globalHandle.newView;

    var newView = new View();
    globalHandle.newView = newView;
}
```

Also, you can refer to `globalHandle.newView` from any part of your application to check whether it exists.